# Debug more than one target with CMake and Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, cmake, visual-studio-2019

I've a CMake project with two projects: a process that send and receives messages through the network, and a stub that I use for sending and receiving test data from the process.

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 for managing the CMake projects.

How can I start two targets at the same time, in order to start both the stub and the process for debugging them?

Comment: Run two Visual Studios.

Comment: @arrowd If I try to open two visual studio instances on the same solution/cmake project Intellisense complains and I've some other minor problems. Using the same Visual studio instance would be better, considering that it's possible with projects based on solutions.

Comment: Hum, dunno then. It was never a problem for me.